# Using git clone "ssh://" within Dockerfile

Tags: git, docker, ubuntu, ssh, gerrit

I am trying to clone a company repository from Gerrit within a Dockerfile.

I have no problems providing my private SSH key to the image without keeping them there (using multistage build).

My problem is that the company repo on Gerrit requires git clone via ssh:

```
git clone "ssh://usr@gerrit.com:port/path/to/repo
```

I'm attempting to do this with the buildKit experimentals.
The run command in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone usr@gerrit.com:port/path/to/repo /image/path
```

But that doesn't tell *git* to use ssh, and so it will just use its standard protocol and port.

Doing this within the Dockerfile, produces the following error

```
#14 0.659 Cloning into '/image/path'...                                                                                                                                                                         
#14 0.890 Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' to the list of known hosts.
#14 6.740 Permission denied, please try again.
#14 6.774 Received disconnect from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22:2: Too many authentication failures
#14 6.774 Disconnected from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22
#14 6.774 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
#14 6.774 
#14 6.774 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
#14 6.774 and the repository exists.
```

The error clearly states that it attempts to use port 22, although I have specified otherwise.

If I use `RUN git clone "ssh://usr@gerrit.com:port/path/to/repo"` it states that it cannot find the remote repo. 
**It is only in the Dockerfile that this command fails, as this is the standard way in my company to clone our repos.**

The full Dockerfile is here:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
# Using multistage build, where intermediate stage is used for cloning private repo from gerrit
FROM ubuntu as intermediate

# install git
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git openssh-client

# add credentials on build
ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/
RUN echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa && chmod 400 /root/.ssh/id_rsa

# Add gerrit to known hosts
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan gerrit.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

# Clone our repo from gerrit
RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone usr@gerrit.com:port/path/to/repo /image/path

# Actual build stage here
FROM ubuntu:18.04
...
```

Is there any other way to explicitly use **ssh** connection when using `git clone` in a **Dockerfile**?

Comment: Do you need a proxy or a different DNS to reach the repo server?

Comment: I never do when cloning normally, so I suppose no.

Answer (score 0):

When using ssh, you need to make sure you set the correct permissions to the `.ssh` directory and the `private keys`

Set the permission of `/root/.ssh` directory to 700

and `/root/.ssh/id_rsa` private key to 600 in your Dockerfile

```
chmod 700 /root/.ssh && \
chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Also, make sure your ssh keys are setup properly. Test them locally before moving ahead.

Comment: Doesn't work, disconnects immediately - it then complains that there are not the correct access rights.
Again, cloning locally outside the dockerfile works perfectly.

Comment: Is this the command you use locally `git clone ssh://usr@gerrit.com:29418/path/to/repo`

Then try the same syntax in Dockerfile, 
`RUN git clone ssh://usr@gerrit.com:29418/path/to/repo`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the wrong port, Gerrit uses 29418 as the port number for the ssh connections and not the default ssh port 22.

You state that you specify the port otherwise, how did you do that? Have you tried hard coding the correct port number in the Dockerfile?

Comment: Yes I state the port 29418 in the git clone command:
`git clone "ssh://usr@gerrit.com:29418/path/to/repo`
When I wrote *port* in the question, that was implied that it was the port used for Gerrit

Comment: But as the error in the question suggests, it still uses port 22 - is there another way I can specify the port number?

Comment: You can use `ssh -p 29418`

Comment: Oh, it looks like you are using two ssh connections, one to gerrit, and one to run the command.